# A question on a continuous, nonegative function

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous, nonegative function and $\alpha$ a root of $f$. I want to find a function $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to \alpha}f(x)g(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \beta}f(x)g(x)=0$ for every root $\beta\neq\alpha$ of $f$.

Comment: This cannot in general be done, e.g. take $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, or take $f(x)$ to be zero in some open interval containing $\alpha$ and maybe with some other zeros elsewhere. Then multiplying by any $g(x)$ cannot get rid of the zero at $x=\alpha.$

Answer (score 0):

Take $g(x)=f(x)/(x-a)^{m+1}$ where m is the multiplicity.

Comment: $g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-\alpha})^{m+1}$?